# Cada vez que le doy a un boton que se cree un elemento con id diferente

Tags: javascript, ajax, script

En resumen tengo una función que es la siguiente:

```
 function datos3(){
    resp=$("#ref_mi").val();
    if(resp != "" && resp !=null &&typeof resp != undefined){
        jqmSimpleMessage('Agrega cotizacion: '+resp);
            $.ajax({
            url: "rest/orden/item1/"+resp,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

                $.each(data, function (index, value) {

                   $("#matricula1").append('<a class="ui-btn ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child" id="ref1" name="id_item" value="'+value.id_item+'" onclick="limpiar1()">'+value.id_marca+'-'+value.id_item+'-'+value.nomItem+'-'+value.nomMarca+'</a> <a  id="lo1" value="'+value.id_marca+'" name="id_marca" style="display:none;">'+value.id_marca+'</a>');

                });

            },
            error: function(error){
                {
                    if(error.status==401){
                        desAuth();
                    }
                    jqmSimpleMessage("Error en listar infor empleado: "+error.responseText);
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + getVCookie(getVCookie("userPro"))); }
        });
    }else{
        jqmSimpleMessage('Error escoje un Producto');
    }
}
```

Esta función lo que hace es recoger los datos que consulto en base a un id. Después lo imprime en un div llamado matricula1 en forma de un botón, mi inquietud es que quiero que cada vez que creo un botón en ese div(Matricula1) quiero que los id de cada botón sean diferentes y no se muy bien como hacerlo

Por ejemplo que si ese boton tiene Id="refmi" que el siguiente que se cree sea Id="refmi1"

Comment: al igual como hiciste +value.id_item+, pondrías id="ref' +value.id+' " (o el campo que devuelva el id)

Comment: porque no usas el mismo `value.id_item` que traes de la base dedatos para asignar la id al boton?

Comment: @AndySamuel creo que tu solucion es algo buena voy aver si ala hora de registrar los datos no entra en conflicto

Comment: la solucion de @AndySamuel es buena, y yo la llegue a usar, solo que cuando tienes ids autoincrement y si hubo un intento fallido de insercion se perderia la secuencia y a la hora de capturar no sabras cual es cual (ya me sucedio) .-.

Comment: @srJJ Xd sucedio una cosa ya no los puedo eliminar :V como el id cambia help please

Comment: eso era prescisamente a lo que me referia, cuando hay un intento fallido de insercion el id sigue su curos dejando un vacion, o cuando hay eliminaciones tambien quedaran esos vacios

Comment: @srJJ como puedo hacer para que al dar click sobre ese elemento se elimine solo me faltaria eso por que los id ya se generan consecutivamente

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que buscas, pero puedes hacer esto:

```
function datos3(i){
resp=$("#ref_mi"+i).val();
//codigo 
}
```

Pero lo mejor parece ser usar clases en lugar de id's.

Comment: Gracias lo voy a intentar

Comment: :( no funciono pero gracia

Comment: es que aqui lo que hara es tratar de capturar algun valor de un div que no existe

Comment: @srJJ ah claro, el id lo tiene que crear

Comment: @franciscoayala esta respuesta es asumiendo que creas los id dinamicamente, porque no se como los creas. si existe #ref_mi1, #ref_mi2 va a funcionar cuando llames a la funcion datos3 dinamicamete también

Comment: @Emeeus amigo el valor de ref_mi lo que hace es traer el Id del item con ese serializo la consulta para que solo me salgan los items que estan con un proveedor

Answer (score 0):

Declara una variable fuera del escope de la funcion para que su vida sea hasta que se cierre o se recargue la pagina

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  var nuevoId=0;
//se inicia en 0 para que al primero tenga algun valor
function datos3(){
resp=$("#ref_mi").val();
if(resp != "" && resp !=null &&typeof resp != undefined){
    jqmSimpleMessage('Agrega cotizacion: '+resp);
        $.ajax({
        url: "rest/orden/item1/"+resp,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, value) {

              var elemento = "";
                  //creamos el primer boton con su id cambiante
              elemento += '<a class="ui-btn ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child" id="ref'+nuevoId+'" name="id_item" value="'+value.id_item+'" onclick="limpiar('+nuevoId+')">'+value.id_marca+'-'+value.id_item+'-'+value.nomItem+'-'+value.nomMarca+'</a>'
                          //creamos el segundo boton
                          //aqui tambien le ponemos un id cambiante para que se pa cual debe eliminar
              elemento += '<a  id="lo'+nuevoId+'" value="'+value.id_marca+'" name="id_marca" style="display:none;">'+value.id_marca+'</a>'

               $("#matricula1").append(elemento);
            //antes de terminar incrementas el valor de la variable
            //en el primer caso el id sera "ref0" y en segundo "ref1"


            nuevoId = nuevoId + 1;
            });

        },
        error: function(error){
            {
                if(error.status==401){
                    desAuth();
                }
                jqmSimpleMessage("Error en listar infor empleado: "+error.responseText);
            }
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + getVCookie(getVCookie("userPro"))); }
    });
}else{
    jqmSimpleMessage('Error escoje un Producto');
}

function limpiar(valor){ 
  //conatenamos el nombre base con el id cambiante
  $("#ref"+valor).remove(); 
  $("#lo"+valor).remove(); 
}
</script>
```

**Esto si no quieres contar con los valores de BD y que se indenpendiente para capturar luego, ya que los values de la BD pueden ser muy cambiantes**

**Actualizacion** Modifique un poco la forma del codigo para que sea haga mas facil el mantenimiento y la solucion de errores poniendo los elementos por separado. (la logica sigue siendo la misma)

espero te sirva bro, me cuentas

Comment: Gracias pero la idea es poder capturar los datos que estan en ese elemento y si hago un contador creo que no serviria pero muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: una ves sabiendo que todos los `id` seran consecutivos con su nombre seria mas facil capturar su contenido .-.

Comment: mmm voy probar si funciona al momento de registrar

Comment: @franciscoayala en el mismo momento que creas el boton le pasas ese mismo valor al boton o a la funcion que borra en tu caso supongo que es `limpiar()` le pasar ese mismo valor, y luego dentro de la funcion ejecutas el borrado de ese id

Comment: no te entendi esta parte perdon :(

Comment: pone el codigo desde donde quieres borar el elemento que creaste

Comment: function limpiar(){
 $("#ref").remove();
 $("#lo").remove();
}

Comment: asi era como lo eliminaba

Comment: function limpiar(){
 $("#ref").remove();
 $("#lo").remove();
}

Comment: en el codigo veo que es `onclick="limpiar1()"` con un 1 es otro o es ese mismo ?

Comment: @franciscoayala, mira he modificado mi respuesta, para que puedas eliminar el elemento que creas

Answer (score 0):

Despues de preguntarle a mi jefe xd

```
function datos3(){
resp=$("#ref_mi").val().split("-");
cant=$("#canti").val();
precio=$("#precio").val();
buscado= $("#item-"+resp[0]*1+"-"+resp[1]*1).val();


if(buscado != "" ||  buscado !=null || buscado != undefined ){

    if(resp != "" && resp !=null &&typeof resp != undefined){

        jqmSimpleMessage('Agrega producto: '+resp[0]*1+"-"+resp[1]*1);

        $("#matricula1").append('<a class="ui-btn ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child" id="item-'+resp[0]*1+"-"+resp[1]*1+'" name="id_item" value="'+resp[0]*1+"-"+resp[1]*1+"-"+cant+"-"+precio+'" onclick="limpiar1()">'+resp[2]+"x"+cant+" $"+precio+'</a> '); 
    }else{
        jqmSimpleMessage('Error en la seleccion del producto');
    }

}else{
    jqmSimpleMessage('Error Ya existe est producto');
}
```

}

```
function limpiar1(){
$("#item-"+resp[0]*1+"-"+resp[1]*1).remove();
```

}